# How to make a flexgrid column to a checkbox column

Tags: checkbox, vb6

I have a flexgid with 3 columns. I need to make the first column a checkbox column so that users can check and uncheck there. And i need the other column values which are checked. ` MSFlexGridBrg.Width = "3200"
    For Bea = 1 To NbBearg
        MSFlexGridBrg.Rows = NbBearg + 1
         MSFlexGridBrg.Cols = 3

```
     'MSFlexGridBrg.CellFontName = "Wingdings"
    MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(0, 0) = "Select"
    If MainUnitIn Then
            MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(0, 2) = "Cu (N)"
    Else
            MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(0, 2) = "Cu (lbf)"
    End If

     MSFlexGridBrg.Row = 1
    MSFlexGridBrg.col = 1
    MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(0, 1) = "Bearing No."
        MSFlexGridBrg.Row = Bea
        MSFlexGridBrg.Text = Bea & ". "

        MSFlexGridBrg.col = 1
        MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(MSFlexGridBrg.Row, 2) = Cu_Value_Estimate(Bea)
Next`
```

The output is attached as the image. I want the column named Select as the Checkbox column.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in your current first column, as it is a fixed column which doesn't allow edit. Add a new column and inside your formatting loop (*which isn't clearly to see in your code sample, but i see there is the* `next` *at the very bottom*) use a standard formatting code:

```
   If myBooleanVar = True Then  
       MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(i, 0) = "Yes"  
   Else  
       MSFlexGridBrg.TextMatrix(i, 0) = "No"  
   End If
```

If you need to use the first cell of the column to select all the rows, you may use the `MSFlexGridBrg_Click()` and then check for `MSFlexGridBrg.MouseCol = -1` and `MSFlexGridBrg.MouseRow = -1` - but a checkbox won't never appear.